# Swift and Foundation relationship

Tags: ios, swift2, foundation

As a newcomer to iOS Development i want to understand the relationship between Swift 2 and Foundation Framework

I already know that Swift is just a programming language and Foundation is a framework build on Objective-C.

What i don't understand is when i need to use Foundation classes or just stay at pure Swift.

For eg. when i have a Swift string do i always need to inherit from NSString for functionality i can't find in pure Swift strings?

Yesterday i was looking for a case-insensitive comparison between two Swift string. One of the solutions i found was that:

```
var a : String = "Cash"
var b  : String = "cash"

if(a.caseInsensitiveCompare(b) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedSame){
    println("voila")
}
```

This bring me a lot of frustration. How can a Swift string has a function(caseInsensitiveCompare) that doesn't exist in pure Swift?

Did the string inherit it from somewhere and how?

Please give me an overall explanation for when i need the foundation as a superset of Swift. Which part of foundation are no longer needed by me as a developer who skip Objective-C for Swift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can a Swift string has
>   a function(caseInsensitiveCompare) that doesn't exist in pure Swift?

It's because you imported Foundation (or UIKit, which includes Foundation) and because Swift String is *bridged* to Foundation NSString. This causes many (but not all) NSString methods to spring to life for String.

If you had *not* imported Foundation, you would *not* have been able to do what you did: `caseInsensitiveCompare` would not have been present.

Comment: And see my free online book, which discusses this further: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch03.html#_string

Comment: Ok this make the things more clear. Can you explain a bit more the 'bridged' definition.

Comment: "Bridged" means, for purposes of your question, exactly what I said in my answer. For more information, please read the link I gave you. My book explains all about this. Or just read the Swift documentation.

Answer (score 1):

The Foundation framework has its roots in NeXTSTEP, from the early days of Objective C. It's a great framework, but admittedly it's dated and lacks a lot of modern programming principles, and doesn't take advantage of many of Swift's new shiny toys. Apple is working on revitalizing Foundation for Swift 3.

I would steer clear of using Foundation anytime a pure Swift solution is available.

In your case, you can do case-insensitive comparison by converting both strings to lower case and comparing them:

```
if a.lowercaseString == b.lowercaseString {
    //Strings match
}
```

I would actually roll it into an extension of `String`:

```
extension String {
    func equalsIgnoringCase() -> Bool {
        return a.lowercaseString == b.lowercaseString
    }
}

//then:

if a.equalsIgnoringCase(b) {
    //Strings match
}
```